# Displaying symfony object values in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

Im new to Symfony / Twig and am having problems passing object values to my twig templates.

Here is some of my controller code that shows the content of the object:

```
$prevArticles = $section->getArticles();      
print_r($prevArticles);
die()
```

Displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Imagine\NewsletterBundle\Entity\Article Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 
            [title:protected] => 
            [headline:protected] => 
            [link:protected] => 
            [image:protected] => 
            [excerpt:protected] => 
            [check:protected] => 
            [attachment:protected] => 
            [field1:protected] => 
            [field2:protected] => 
            [field3:protected] => 
            [magazines:protected] => 
            [top_logo_advert:protected] => /uploaded_images/cece0b1859ea2b1af95f1f274620ba77.jpg
            [top_logo_alt:protected] => Picture of blomange
            [top_logo_link:protected] => www.google.com
        )

)
```

So then I pass my object to my twig template like so:

```
    return $this->render('ImagineNewsletterBundle:Section:'.$builder->getTemplate(), array('prevArticles' => $prevArticles));
```

Then in my twig template I want to display the value of 'top_logo_advert' but its not working:

```
{% for article in prevArticles %}

   {{ article.top_logo_advert }}

{% endfor %}
```

I get the error message:

```
Method "top_logo_advert" for object "Imagine\NewsletterBundle\Entity\Article" does not exist in ImagineNewsletterBundle:Section:build_advert.html.twig at line 62
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must access it via :

`{{ article.topLogoAdvert }}` or `{{ article.getTopLogoAdvert() }}`

Both solutions works. Next time, just reminder that properties like `'my_property_1'` is converted into `myProperty1` in the twig engine.

Comment: Great stuff. I implemented {{ article.topLogoAdvert }} and it worked. So whats the deal with Twig changing variable names then? I assumed that top_logo_advert would have worked?

Comment: Because you are supposed to follow at least PSR-0 conventions. It means that in the first place you're not supposed to declare porperty on your object with one or multiple underscore(s). Use camel case properties and variable instead.

Comment: Ok noted. I'll go back and rename my variables. Cheers

Comment: Just a note in case this relates to OP or anyone else that stumbles upon this post – non-public properties that you're attempting to access via the magic `__get()` method won't get to Twig unless you also define `__isset()` in your class. See: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-dynamic-object-properties